# replication server with same id in docker/openshift cluster

Tags: opendj

I'm having problems when setting up replication in openshift/docker cluster.

In openshift, each opendj server will have two ips: service ip and pod id. So when I setup two opendj service, two service ip and two pod ip will be there.

I want to set up the replication by service ip, because pod is is not accessible from other pod, but apparently OpenDJ think there are four replication server there, with each two server having same ServerId.

Log snippet:

category=SYNC severity=ERROR msgID=org.opends.messages.replication.55 msg=In Replication server Replication Server 8989 31635: replication servers 172.30.244.127(service ip):8989 and 10.129.0.1:8989(pod ip) have the same ServerId : 11281

My Question is: is it possible to just build the Replication Server cluster by Service IP, not Pod id?

Thanks a lot.

PS: seems this issue is similar with this https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENDJ-567

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, please config your opendj service to headless service, that will solve the problem